# live reload web server of twistd

Tags: python, webserver, twisted

I'm using twistd as web server to work in front end of web. I want to reload browser automatically when my file changes. How to config twistd command line to achieve it.

I start twistd from command line: `twistd -no web --path=. --port=8888`

Comment: A webserver by pure HTTP can not reload the page on the client. For these you need push technologies like websockets.

Comment: I think the #soarinblue want's a feature similar to Flask's debug mode. Unfortunately I don't think there's such a feature by default.